# How Do I check Permissions of Root Folder (/ Folder, not /root)?

Tags: permissions

Is there a way to check the permissions of the root folder, /? I mean the folder's permissions, not its content's (/var, /usr, etc.) permissions? Running `ls /..` shows the content's permissions.

Comment: Have you tried the `-l` option:

     `ls -l /`

Comment: Yes, it shows the contents; I wanted the contents of the outer folder, which doesn't technically exist. The question is already answered anyway.

Comment: Can you please edit your title to not include the text "/root", because web searched for "/root " come here and that doesn't make any sense.   Perhaps you could just say (/), and then lower down in the text clarify that you are not referring to /root.   Thanks

Comment: If I did that, people would come here looking for `/root` folder permissions, which also does not make sense. I'll be damned if I do, damned if I don't.

Comment: -1 Because you have not yet changed the title to simply /, I came here looking for permission of /root (because that's how google works.)

Answer (score 63, accepted):

You can also use the `-d` switch of `ls`:

```
$ ls -ld /
drwxr-xr-x 28 root root 126976 Mar 20 17:11 /
```

From `man ls`:

```
   -l     use a long listing format
   -d, --directory
          list  directory entries instead of contents, and do not derefer‐
          ence symbolic links
```

Answer (score 24):

`stat -c "%a %n" /`

It will give you the permissions.

Comment: Thanks, that was fast. `stat` seems like an interesting, useful command, having read its `man` page.

Comment: You should use the `a` switch to see the permissions of `.` which corresponds to root home.

Comment: Yeah, that's what the other answer says, and what I should have thought of. D'oh!

Comment: ha ha. You can accept either of the 2 answers. Both the answers seem to suit what you need :)

Comment: Ugh, I wish I could accept both. They're both perfect!

Comment: No issues. Next time, you can use either of these commands and this is how you can learn new commands :)

Answer (score 16):

Use the `-a` switch of `ls` to include hidden files as well as `.` and `..` in the listing and the `-l` switch for a "long" listing (which includes the permissions, among other information):

```
ls -la /
```

The line with a single `.` in the last column will contain information about the listed directory itself, i.e. `/`:

> drwxr-xr-x  26 root root  4096 Mar 10 15:57 .

However if you only need information about `/` itself, [terdon's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/121296/28235) (using the `-d` switch) will probably be handier.

Comment: @trysis I routinely use `ls -blah`. It has everything you could possibly want to know about a file or directory.

Comment: Yeah, I've switched to -A because `.` and `..` are there anyway, but if I had stayed with -a I wouldn't have needed to ask this question.

Comment: This is not really a very good solution, it will list all files under `/` when all the OP wanted was `/` itself. See `stat` or `ls -ld` in the answers below.

Comment: @terdon I wanted to stick with `ls` as the OP seemed familiar with it. You are definitely right about `-d` though; I didn't know about that one (and didn't notice it in the manpage either).

Comment: @trysis You might want to accept terdon's answer instead since it's closer to what you originally wanted to achieve.

Comment: Fair enough, the comment was not so much directed at you as to future users who might see this as the accepted answer and assume it is the Best Way® to do it.

Comment: `.` is not necessarily first. The list is sorted lexically. There are several characters that sort before `.` in many locales.

Comment: @StephaneChazelas I have yet to encounter that problem, but you could use `-U` (*unsorted*) to have `.` and `..` as the first entries.

Comment: There's no reason for `.` or `..` to come first with `-U` (and in my test, they don't: `ls -a` gives `%test%  .  ..  foo` and `ls -Ua` gives `%test%  .  foo  ..`)

Comment: @StephaneChazelas You're right, that was nonsense.